# Autocomplete Multiple separated by "|" not ","

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am following everything as directed in this site:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

except for terms separated by "," I am using character "|" to separate values.

```
$("#txtProjectNameAdd")
        .bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ProjectNameListMulti", "ProjectAssignment")', {
                    term: extractLast(request.term)
                }, response);
            },
            search: function () {
                var term = extractLast(this.value);
                if (term.length < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function () {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join("| ");
                return false;
            }
        });

 function split(val) {
        return val.split(/|\s*/);  
    }

 function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
```

I think there is a problem with Split function. According to the jquery auto complete website the split function is

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
```

so I replaced ',' by '|', but the auto-complete becomes unresponsive with the change. How do i customize the split function.

Comment: make a jsfiddle and post the link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| is a special character in regex so it must be escaped by preceding it with a \

Try using

```
/\|\s*/
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Andrew. Where can i learn more about special character in regex

Comment: Everything you could want to know and then some is at this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html